Android lifecycle methods don't get called correctly
I have a react native app and I need to listen to the android lifecycle events in MainActivity.kt. I added a Log.d to every of the lifecycle methods to see when each get's called. The problem I am facing right now is that there doesn't seem to be a pattern when onCreate get's called. Sometimes onCreate get's called when the process is starting, sometimes the process starts without calling any of the lifecycle methods. As far as I can tell, the other methods get called correctly.
I use android:launchMode="singleTop" because I need to listen to NFC intents in the app.
What could be causing this behavoir?

The odds of there actually being an issue calling lifecycle functions is incredibly low.  More likely you're misinterpreting when they should be called.  To help, we'd need a lot more detail on when you aren't getting them when you think you should, what you did before that time to set up this scenario, and what calls you are getting.  Your use of the term "process" loosely here doesn't help, as the OS process starts when the app starts and ends when the app ends.  So I assume you mean something else.
